# Need Help In Making C++ Template For Printing Vector<pair<int,int>>

Tags: c++, c++14

I have already created a template for printing vector, see below

```
template<class T> void  _print(vector<T> v1){cerr<<"[ ";for(T i:v1){_print(i);cerr<<" ";}cerr<<"]";}
```

But the problem is that i also wanted to create template for printing vector<pair<int,int>>  but i don't know how i can create new one for pair<int,int>, that uses the same macro debug().

**code that I use.**

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#define vi vector<int>
#define ui unordered_set<int>
#define all(v) v.begin(),v.end()
#define lower(s) transform(all(s) ,s.begin(),::tolower)
#define upper(s) transform(all(s),s.begin(),::toupper)
#define sortv(v) sort(all(v))
#define rev(v) reverse(all(v))
#define f first
#define s second
#define int long long int
#define float double 
#define endl "\n"
#define null NULL
using namespace std;
#ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE
#define debug(x) cerr << #x << " ";_print(x); cerr<<endl;
#else
#define debug(x)
#endif

void _print(int a){cerr<<a;}
void _print(float a){cerr<<a;}
void _print(char a){cerr<<a;}
void _print(bool a){cerr<<a;}
void _print(string a){cerr<<a;}

template<class T> void  _print(set<T> s1){cerr<<"[ ";for(T i:s1){_print(i);cerr<<" ";}cerr<<"]";}
template<class T> void  _print(vector<T> v1){cerr<<"[ ";for(T i:v1){_print(i);cerr<<" ";}cerr<<"]";}

int32_t main()
{
#ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE
    freopen("Error.txt","w",stderr);
#endif



    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you don't have an overload of `_print` for the argument type pair, so your template instantiation for `T = std::pair<int,int>` does not compile.

If you declare another function such as below, it should work.

```
void _print(const std::pair<int, int> &a) {
  cerr<< "{"; _print(a.first); cerr << ", "; _print(a.second); cerr << "}";
}
```